# File manager doesn't mount NTFS partitions

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I have dual boot and I keep all my data in separate partition and now I am not able to open that partition in freya.

Comment: Is the partition displayed in the file manager at all, in the sidebar or computer directory? Does it display any error message? Sometimes mounting can take several minutes for large disks that are slightly corrupted, have you tried simply waiting a while?

Comment: Which is your second operating system? I'm assuming it's Windows, but I'm interested in which version of Windows are you dual booting with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows 8:

- Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > System Settings or search on the main menu `power options`
  [image]
- Choose `Change what the power buttons do`
- Press `Change settings that are currently unavailable`
  [image]
- Uncheck `Turn on fast start-up`.
  [image]

This should avoid any problems in the future with unmountable partitions. For safety, shutdown your windows with your `Ctrl` key pressed, it forces a regular shutdown.

If that doesn't fix the issue, that's when you should follow Dusan's indications.

if you don't change this setting in your Windows you might run into this issue everytime you boot into elementary OS coming from Windows.

Source and pics: [Dual Mount issues](http://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/)

One of the many accounts I've seen of corruptions happening after ntfsfix:
[Don’t use ntfsfix in Linux, just turn off Fast Boot in Windows](https://sudopacman.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/dont-use-ntfsfix-in-linux-just-turn-off-fast-boot-in-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 8 and later, you might be experiencing problems like that if you didn't shut down Windows correctly.

Anyhow, try this:

1) find your partition with `sudo fdisk -l` under device column(something like `/dev/sda1`)

2) `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`

3) Try to mount it again

Comment: Forcing the mount of an hibernated partition could possibly ruin data on the disk, does ntfsfix take that into account or does it simply force the partition to allow mounting?

Comment: From ntfsfix man page:

ntfsfix  is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.  ntfsfix is
       NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some  fundamental  NTFS
       inconsistencies,  resets  the  NTFS  journal file and schedules an NTFS
       consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

       You may run ntfsfix on an NTFS volume if you think it  was  damaged  by
       Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted.

Comment: I've seen more complaints of it but this is one of them: https://sudopacman.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/dont-use-ntfsfix-in-linux-just-turn-off-fast-boot-in-windows/

Comment: Turning off fast start-up is definitely a good thing when you use both Windows and Linux.

I cannot prove that it's perfectly safe in any situation but I have been using it for a very long time in cases like this and haven't ran in any kind of problems.